# add and substract days from CDate object

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a CDate object .How can i add and substract  some days to this CDate object.I am geeting cdate object from jquery calenders datepicker. you can read about this from [here](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPicker.html#getset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this page: http://keith-wood.name/calendarsRef.html#cdate there's a function called add(offset, period) that you can call from the CDate object.

> Add a number of periods to this date. If changing by month or year and the new month has fewer days, the day is adjusted to the end of that new month. You can also add periods from the calendar.
>
> offset (number) is the amount of change, which may be negative.
>
> period (string) is the unit of change: 'y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days.

```
date.add(1, 'w'); 
date.add(-18, 'm'); 
date.add(1, 'y').add(1, 'd');
```